# Binary image classification TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile()`

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, typeerror

```
model.compile(
optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
loss= [keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True)
      ], 
metrices= ['accuracy'])

model.fit(ds_train, epochs= 10, verbose=2)
```

TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile()`: ({'metrices'},). Valid keyword arguments include "cloning", "experimental_run_tf_function", "distribute", "target_tensors", or "sample_weight_mode".

Comment: It's `metrics`, not `metrices`.

Answer (score 5):

check your spelling.. its "metrics" ..

```
model.compile(
optimizer= keras.optimizers.Adam(), 
loss= keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True), 
metrics= ['accuracy'])

model.fit(ds_train, epochs= 10, verbose=2)
```

Comment: You should write the correct solution instead of the same incorrect piece of code, thus confusion would be avoided.